# Is it possible to fix slideUp /slideDown jquery jump issue for responsive width

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

There have been a lot of posts about the slideUp/slideDown jump, the [most helpful of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092245/basic-jquery-slideup-and-slidedown-driving-me-mad) points to [Remy Sharp's post](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slidedown-animation-jump-revisited/). This, however only addresses the situation if the height of the div to be hidden doesn't change.

Let's say the html looks like:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Content</p>
<h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Content</p>
<h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Content</p>
```

The jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $listing = $('p');
    var $listingTitle = $('h3')


$listing.addClass('hide');


$listingTitle.click(function(){

    if ($(this).next("p").hasClass("active-listing") === true) {
      $listing.slideUp(500).removeClass("active-listing");
    } else {


$listing.slideUp(500).removeClass("active-listing");
  $(this).next("p").slideDown(500).addClass("active-listing");

    }

});


});
```

If I were to employ Remy's fix (which I've tried) it works perfectly at first. But in a responsive site the height of each `<p>` changes if the browser is resized manually. Then the new length of each

is different and can cause major spacing issues. Is there a way to get rid of the jumping issue without adding a specific width to the div or querying the height?

Comment: You might not be able to use it, but I was able to get around the jumpiness by using `float:left` along with `width:100%`. http://jsfiddle.net/RskHZ/

Comment: @motoxer4533 I see that it works in the fiddle–maybe because on the full site this is actually nested inside other divs with width in %'s this solution won't work for me. Not sure, just tried it and still having jumpiness.