# Div is not sliding up correctly when clicking on it

Tags: jquery

I have one div that slides up after clicking on a button/link, but it seems to move down slightly first and then backup which makes it look a bit strange. When clicking the button/link it should just slide upwards without moving down first.

here is the jquery code that i am using:

```
 $(document).ready(function($){
    $('#hide_cookie').click(function() {
      $('.cookie').slideUp('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
```

this is the html code:

```
<div class="cookie">
    <div class="container_12">
        <span>header here</span>
        <p>tex there</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
       <a href="#" id="hide_cookie" class="read-more">Continue</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092245/basic-jquery-slideup-and-slidedown-driving-me-mad (probably the same issue).

Comment: Thanks, I found it usefull!!! Addinga max-height for the div resolved the problem!

Comment: YOu should add this as a answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element needs to have a height property. Otherwise jQuery wont do a smooth animation.

#### Read more

> [Basic jQuery slideUp and slideDown driving me mad!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092245/basic-jquery-slideup-and-slidedown-driving-me-mad)

Answer (score 0):

try `event.preventDefault()`

here

```
 $('#hide_cookie').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.cookie').slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```