# "More" functionality for comments problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a "More" functionality for comments.

How I'm trying to make it work:

- I split comment in 2 parts - 1st 200 symbols and the rest of the symbols.
- The rest of the symbols are placed in a `<span class="hidden_comment_container" ></span>` which by default gets `display:none`
- Toggle to show the rest is placed if needed (if comment length > 200 symbols).

This is working more or less fine ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ3cJ/3/)) but there are 2 problems.

1. Upon slidedown, `hidden_comment_container` receives `display:inline-block` and messes up things a bit, since it gets transferred to a new line (check demo to see what I mean)
2. When sliding down and sliding up, near the end of animation you can notice some twitching.

Can anyone please help me solve these 2 problems?

Comment: The third problem is, that there should be some text in the "toggle" button to really toggle [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPUdj/)... ; ).

Comment: There is. check `toggle_up` css on the right `content:"△"`

Comment: I can see the CSS, but there's no buttons on the page...

Answer (score 0):

The first one can be resolved by adding the following to the case when the remaining text is hidden.

```
$(this).next(".comment_container").children('.hidden_comment_container').slideDown('medium', function() { 
        $('.hidden_comment_container').css('display', 'inline');
    });
```

Basically you're changing the `display` attribute of the `.hidden_comment_container` selector as I believe `slideDown` is adding a `display:inline-block` to it which would cause it to jump a line.

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ3cJ/6/)**

Answer to point 2 can be found in [Basic jQuery slideUp and slideDown driving me mad!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092245/basic-jquery-slideup-and-slidedown-driving-me-mad/1092884#1092884); basically you need to explicitly add the height of the element before hiding / showing it.

As a side note the css property `content` can only be used with the pseudo elements `:after` and `:before`; I updated my fiddle accordingly.

#### An alternative solution

Have a look at this script, it does everything you need! I tested it already on another project and it works like a charm: [jquery plugin to truncate elements based on height instead of number of characters](https://gist.github.com/wireframe/75088)

Comment: Even though it does the trick, it looks kinda ugly. Maybe it would look better if display was changed at the start of the animation instead of when animation is completed. As for 2nd problem, toggle and observe bottom border

Comment: Nevermind content, I just used it for fiddle, on site I use picture from sprite.

Comment: 1. don't think you can have both, sliding and inline as the sliding happens vertically and inline is horizontal... 2. you mean that it's gradually sliding, row by row instead of consistently?

Comment: you could potentially solve the "ugliness" of 1 by quickly hiding the beginning of that line (before the 3 dots), and then apply the slideDown to that and the rest of the text... if it makes sense...

Comment: how am I even supposed to do that? And no, I mean how it's twitching at the end of animation.

Comment: according to https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ there it should be possible to call function when animation start. Not sure how to do that

Comment: I added a solution for point 2, no more twitching... ;) and for the whole thing, I also included a good, already working and tested script for read more... ;)